# Android TextView onDraw Applying Matrix Transformation

Tags: android, matrix, textview, gesture

In order to have TextViews support move, scale, and rotate gestures, I've extended the TextView class and overridden its `onDraw(Canvas)` method apply a matrix transformation from an input matrix.

The matrix appears to be correct, but it does not look like the text view is being redrawn. Any help on figuring this out would be much appreciated.

**Update: The below updates the view, but will violate the clipping bounds**

```
canvas.save();
canvas.concat(mMatrix);
// Call onDraw before restore (after updating the matrix)
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Original Code:

```
public class GestureTextView extends TextView implements IGestureView
{
    private Matrix mMatrix;

    public GestureTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mMatrix = getMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMatrix(Matrix matrix)
    {
        mMatrix = matrix;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: call `super.onDraw(canvas);` **after** you changed the current `Matrix`, btw use `concat`, not `setMAtrix`

Comment: @pskink Tried both of your suggestions. Unfortunately, this does not appear to work :/

Comment: how come? see http://codeshare.io/V433N

Comment: @pskink hmm, what layout are you using? I'm using a RelativeLayout

Comment: did u get the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation **restore** does the next `This call balances a previous call to save(), and is used to remove all modifications to the matrix/clip state since the last save call. It is an error to call restore() more times than save() was called.`

So, what you do here is

1. Save the canvas.
2. Apply modified matrix
3. Reset to the saved canvas

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
   ```